# Installing a theme for rEFInd and finding rEFInd file MAC

Tags: themes, refind

So I am attempting to add a theme to rEFInd, as I don't like how it looks, but I am a complete newbie when it comes to terminal and looking for usually hidden files.  This is the theme I'm trying to use: [Minimal Theme](http://evanpurkhiser.com/rEFInd-minimal/), and this is how you are supposed to install it:

```
   # cd /boot/EFI/refind/
   # git clone https://github.com/EvanPurkhiser/rEFInd-minimal
   # echo "include refind-minimal/theme.conf" >> refind.conf
   # systemctl reboot
```

Anyways, I have installed rEFInd correctly (I hope, as it said install complete) but I cannot find where it is supposed to be.  `locate refind.conf` to no avail. Every time I tun the command above, I get `cd: /boot/EFI/refind/: No such file or directory` making it so it won't correctly install.

And one last question, I ran `diskutil list` and it said I have two EFI disks (is that what it's called?). Is that normal? Any other tutorial I look out, they only have one EFI.

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            700.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:        Bios Boot Partition                         3.1 MB     disk0s4
   5:                 Linux Swap                         1.0 GB     disk0s5
   6: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4               298.3 GB   disk0s6
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS FreeAgent GoFlex Drive  499.8 GB   disk1s2
```

I really hope all this made sense, I am just a complete newbie to all of this.

Comment: If you provide me with the commands you used to install refind itself, I should be able to help you locate your refind.conf and related files. Also, with regards to your two EFI partitions, from what I can tell /dev/disk1 is a USB harddrive. If that's the case, you only need to concern yourself with /dev/disk0. ALSO (:p) it doesn't look like you've installed Ubuntu with support. I'm seeing a hybrid table (EFI/EMULATED BIOS). Was this intentional?

Comment: @amanthethy I was in the middle of installing Ubuntu, but in the final part my flash drive broke errored out or something. The command I used to install rEFInd was `sudo /path/to/unzipped_rEFInd file/install.sh` only with the path actually written out.

Comment: You've got to mount your ESP partition as reFind now installs there by default. (It used to install to /boot/EFI) `mkdir /Volumes/EFI && sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/EFI` After this, the folder with your refind stuff should be in /Volumes/EFI/. (ex. /Volumes/EFI/EFI/refind/)

Comment: Okay, so I tried it, and it worked. However when I reentered the way you are supposed to install the theme, but I got this error: `baileys1106s-imac:~ moriarty$     cd /boot/EFI/refind/
-bash: cd: /boot/EFI/refind/: No such file or directory
baileys1106s-imac:~ moriarty$     git clone https://github.com/EvanPurkhiser/rEFInd-minimal
fatal: destination path 'rEFInd-minimal' already exists and is not an empty directory.
baileys1106s-imac:~ moriarty$     echo "include refind-minimal/theme.conf" >> refind.conf
baileys1106s-imac:~ moriarty$     systemctl reboot
-bash: systemctl: command not found`

Comment: Well yeah... Your refind stuff is at /Volumes/EFI/whatever not /boot/EFI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From OSX, do the following

Start by mounting your EFI partition.

`sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes`

Then `cd` to the rEFInd directory on that partition
`cd /Volumes/EFI/rEFInd`

Download the theme with Git

`git clone https://github.com/EvanPurkhiser/rEFInd-minimal`

Now add the theme info to refind.conf

`echo "include rEFInd-minimal/theme.conf" >> refind.conf`

Reboot with `sudo reboot`

Comment: When I did the cd /Volumes/EFI/rEFInd, I got "No such file or directory".  What should I do?

Comment: That's what the folder is called on my machine. I have no idea what it would be called on yours, but I can be sure that whatever it is it will sit in /Volumes/EFI/ after you mount your ESP partition. Check that the spelling and path match what is actually on your machine. `cd` means Change Directory. So if you say `cd /foo/bar` and /foor/bar doesn't exist it'll give you the error you're getting.

Answer (score -2):

ReFIND Minimal Theme on Mac OS X Yosemite

In Terminal...

```
$ cd /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind
$ git clone https://github.com/EvanPurkhiser/rEFInd-minimal
Cloning into 'rEFInd-minimal'...
remote: Counting objects: 182, done.
remote: Total 182 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 182
Receiving objects: 100% (182/182), 3.35 MiB | 6.32 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (74/74), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```